# Why does Entity Framework automatically use the ObjectContext instead of the DbContext when mapping database tables using ADO.NET Entity datamodel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

I am following the database approach first; I have created the tables in my SQL Server 2008 database, then I map those tables to Entity Framework classes using an ADO.NET Entity Data Model. But when I opened the designer.cs file I found the following code in the class definition which was created automatically:

```
public partial class PortalEntities : ObjectContext
```

so I have the following three question that get my confused:

1. Why does my `PortalEntities` class derive from `ObjectContext` and not `DbContext` as I was expecting?
2. Is there a major difference between `ObjectContext` & `DbContext`, or they are mainly the same and offer that same capabilities
3. When I try to write the something similar to the following code:

   ```
   Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
   ```

I found that I cannot use `.Find()` method as I used to do using `DbContext`, so does this mean that `ObjectContext` & `DbContext` have different methods that I can use?

BR

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `DbContext` is a wrapper around the `ObjectContext` which simplifies the interface for the things we do most.

If you have an `DbContext` you can still access the `ObjectContext`trough  `((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;`

If you want to use the `DbContext` instead of the `ObjectContext` when using database first, you can switch the template that's used for generating your code. You can do this by right-clicking in your EDMX and selecting 'Add Code Generation Item'. You can then select the DbContext template.

[Here is an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx) of the whole process.

Comment: thanks for your reply; but will i benefit from using DbContext instead of ObjectContext in my database apprach first ?.

Comment: The DbContext has a simplified interface. It will be easier to use and if necessary you can always cast it to an ObjectContext. Also the DbContext is easier to mock for unit testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Since VS2012 the default code generation changed from `ObjectContext` to `DbContext`.